# Hadoop MapReduce Unable to connect to ResourceManager

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop3

I'm trying to setup Hadoop with a Single Node Cluster (Psuedo-distributed) and using [the apache guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0-alpha3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Execution) to do so. Right now I'm trying to run a MapReduce job and using the example it provides `bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.0.0-alpha3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z]+'`

```
hadoop@hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.0.0-alpha3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z]+'
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx WARN ipc.Client: Failed to connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number: 10
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
```

Looking this issue up online, everyone else that has this problem seem to have it with YARN but not MapReduce. And my hdfs-site.xml is the same as mentioned in the guide:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I ran `jps` although I don't know what I'm looking for here:

```
hadoop@hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
9860 DataNode
10075 SecondaryNameNode
9708 NameNode
11021 Jps
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I looked into `hadoop-hadoop-resourcemanager-hadoop.log` and found this:

```
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8032: starting
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to active state
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @7307ms
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.resourcemanager is not defined
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context cluster
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context logs
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context static
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context cluster
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /cluster/*
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /ws/*
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx,xxx FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
    ...
```

Edit2: here's my yarn-site.xml if it helps:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
        <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Running jps command shows that ResourceManager and Nodemanager are not started.Can you please look into resource manager logs to see the exact cause?

Comment: I tried to setup single cluster using instruction from [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) and it always work. Just give it a try

Comment: Isn't this for Hadoop 1 though? I'm using Hadoop 3

Comment: I found this in the Resource Manager log: `FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager` I'll add more of the logs onto the question

Comment: Your `yarn-site.xml` should be malformed. please check that

Comment: I copied it right off of the apache website, and I haven't ran yarn yet, so I don't think that's it. I posted it up anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Java 9 and for the time being there is no Java 9 support for Hadoop yet. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11123